# Can a Kafka consumer commit an offset in a seperate thread?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, manual

Does Kafka permit one thread or process to consume data from a partition, while another thread or process takes the responsibility of manually committing the offset once the data has been completely processed?

Comment: Can you provide code showing an example of where you are trying this?

Comment: I don't have code yet sorry and I'm working with a complicated pre-existing architecture.   But conceptually this is what we want to do.   Have one stream read a bunch of records off of one topic/partition.   Pass on the records read to other parts of an application perhaps using shared memory across co-resident processes.  They finish doing their analysis, and when they are done commit the offset which was communicated from the reader.

Answer (score 0):

[Direct from the `KafkaConsumer` documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#multithreaded):

> The Kafka consumer is NOT thread-safe. All network I/O happens in the
>   thread of the application making the call.

...

> The only exception to this rule is wakeup(), which can safely be used from an external thread to interrupt an active operation.

So, no it is not recommended to use the consumer outside of one thread, beyond the `wakeup` exception.

Comment: Thanks.   

Actually I should have clarified the use case.   The two threads are coordinating but are living in two seperate processes.  One thread is reading a kafka topic, and when it finishes reading, it's posting stuff in shared memory for another process to analyze and to decide when it's done.   So the two processes are written to coordinate such that only one process reads and posts data, and the other one controls the commit and does other application specific stuff with the data its consumed.

Comment: Both using the same consumer object it sounds like?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe it's possible. As noted above KafkaConsumer objects are not thread safe hence each thread should have its own instance. Both instances should have the same group id and auto-commit should of course be disabled. There are commit methods that take specific partitions and offsets as parameters:
https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync-java.util.Map-
and
https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitAsync-java.util.Map-org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetCommitCallback-

However, I *think* you may not be able to do this when using the automatic group management via the subscribe method (the old high level consumer-style usage) but rather you will have to manage partition assignment manually using assign method (like with the old simple consumer). But you can give the former a try and see if that too is possible.

Comment: Sorry for a belated thanks.   Yup, I was talking about manual partition assignment.